# populate combobox in VBA with array elements

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a VBA procedure (in Excel 2007) where I aspire to set the ListFillRange property of a combobox styled as a list using an array.

I know this works if I right click the combobox and write "Sheet1!$F2:$F17" next to the "ListFillRange" property. I can also do this in code. However, I am interested in dynamically setting the value of this property by assigning it an array.

I know for sure the array works as I tested it; there is probably a syntax error here:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cmbS").ListFillRange = ar
```

when I do this I get:
"Type mismatch" error.

The result of this action should be that the component is populated with the array elements, from element(0) ... to the last element (n-1) of the array. Any pointers, thank you very much!

I also tried:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").cmbS.list = ar
```

and it says "permission denied"

Here are the combobox properties in case it helps:
[image]

After testing and trying, I found this works:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").cmbS.ListFillRange = ""

Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").cmbS.AddItem (ar(i))

Next
```

However, I am interested in populating with **all values at once** for faster effect, **not just adding element by element**.

Comment: if it's slow always set screen updating to false before using additem.

Answer (score 10):

I know its late but maybe it is going to help someone else. At least the  following code works (much faster than element for element) for me.

```
dim arr() as variant

arr = Worksheets("Total").Range("C2:"&lrow).Value
Worksheets("Menu").ComboBox2.List = arr
```

Comment: Thank you Valentin! Worksheets("Menu").ComboBox2.List = arr ==> This is what I needed and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can populate a combobox with the content of an array is by doing it element by element. I find it hard to believe that it would be a notably slow process no matter how large your array is.

Comment: Not quite true - you can assign a 2D array to the `.List` property.  This works for both comboboxes and listboxes, e.g. `MyComboBox.List = My2DArray`