# Populate ListBox on ComboBox selection - `run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)':Type mismatch`

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I am trying to populate a list box with rows that match a combobox selection (in column A)

I keep getting this error when i reach a record that has a match in the worksheet `run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)':Type mismatch`

I am trying to search the range for matching values, then add the entire row of each matching value in the A column to the listbox, if there are none, do nothing. But it seems when there is a match, instead of copying the row to the listbox, I get this error.

My understanding is that if there is no match, "" is printed, if there is a match then ListBox3.AddItem Sheets("ActionItems").Range("A2:C8").... The combobox gets its list from a different sheet within the workbook.

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    Set Rng = Sheets("ActionItems").Range("A2:A50").Find(what:=Me.ComboBox3.Value)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        ListBox3.Value = ""
    Else
       ListBox3.AddItem Sheets("ActionItems").Range("A2:C8")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to add multiple rows at the same time?

Comment: I would try iterating through each of the items in `Range("A2:C8")` and adding them one at a time, i.e. `For each cell in Range("A2:C8"): If cell <> "" Then ListBox3.AddItem cell.Text: Next cell`

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this code will do the job.
There are 2 parts to it

1) First you find all the relevant cells with a match and store them in aray
2) Second you add the corresponding rows for these cells in the list box

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()

' The code below will find all the cells with matching values
' And save them in an array
Dim myrange() As Range, rangestart As Range
k = 0
For i = 1 To 50
        If k = 0 Then
        Set rangestart = Range("A1")
        Else
        Set rangestart = myrange(k).Offset(1)
        End If
    Set Rng = Range(rangestart, Range("A50")).Find(What:=Me.ComboBox3.Value, searchdirection:=xlNext)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    k = k + 1
    ReDim Preserve myrange(1 To k) As Range
    Set myrange(k) = Rng
    End If
Next i

If k = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No matching item found"
    Exit Sub
End If

' This Code will populate the list box

ListBox3.Clear

For i = 1 To UBound(myrange)
    For j = 1 To 7
        ListBox3.AddItem myrange(i).Offset(, j)
    Next j
Next i



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

On [ListBox.AddItem Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/listbox-additem-method-access) it is written that the `Item` Data Type is a `String`

So on the examples on the link, you can have functions to add itens to the end or beginning:

**End:**

```
Function AddItemToEnd(ctrlListBox As ListBox, _ 
 ByVal strItem As String) 

 ctrlListBox.AddItem Item:=strItem 

End Function
```

**Beginning:**

```
Function AddItemToBeginning(ctrlComboBox As ComboBox, _ 
 ByVal strItem As String) 

 ctrlComboBox.AddItem Item:=strItem, Index:=0 

End Function
```

It only changes de Index parameter

So as @J.Fox said, you must make a **loop to Add them one by one on a loop** e.g.:`For each cell in Range("A2:C8"): If cell <> "" Then ListBox3.AddItem cell.Text: Next cell` or by **[Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24889461/7690982)**

And it might be better to use **Exit instead of Change**

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
End Sub
```

---